# Are you still considered to be inside an area of effect when protected by a Globe of Invulnerability?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

Let's imagine the following situation:

We have a party of adventurers: Tom the Wizard, Bob the Cleric and Jerry the Monk. The three adventurers are surrounded by many ill-intended creatures.

Tom casts an 8th-level *globe of invulnerability* (surrounding himself and his friends -- let's say he does not get counterspelled), then Bob the Cleric triggers a Stunning *symbol* (for example, by saying "Activate!") on the ground next to the limit of the *globe* (that Bob had previously inscribed there). The enemies fail their save and are now stunned, but the three adventurers, being inside the *globe*, aren't affected. Jerry now wants to go outside the *globe*, whack an enemy or two, then go back inside the *globe* to end his turn inside of it.

The *symbol* spell, as well as other lingering areas of effect, says that "any creature that enters the sphere or ends its turn there is affected".

**When Jerry leaves the *globe*, is he considered as having entered the *symbol*'s sphere (thus needing to make the saving throw), or was he already considered to be inside of it, even if the *globe* protected him from its effects (thus not having to make the saving throw when he leaves the *globe*)?**

My hesitation relies on the fact that, here, Jerry is within the sphere created by the *symbol*, but the *globe*'s text says that "The barrier also blocks areas of effect that reach its area". Not sure here if the word "blocks" makes it so that you're still considered inside the area or not.

The question also applies for other lingering spells that affect creatures when they enter the area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The globe explicitly *excludes* its area from the area of effect of other spells.

The [*globe of invulnerability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability) spell description states:

> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can't affect creatures or objects within it, even if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot. Such a spell can target creatures and objects within the barrier, but the spell has no effect on them. **Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.**

In your example, Jerry is outside of the area of Bob's [*symbol*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol) while inside the *globe*. Jerry will thus need to make a Wisdom save when he exits the *globe*, for entering the area of effect of the *symbol*.

Comment: Ahh, once again, I had the wrong wording of the spell. Well well well.

Comment: @GaelL: Yep, that's why it's always important to check the description from an official source. Unofficial wikis and such might reword things, causing problems.